# Sybase SMP 2.3.4 synchronization error x86 processor (SG Tab 3 10.1)

Tags: android, x86, fatal-error, sup, sap-smp

I am developing a hybrid application that connects to Sybase through a WebView. When the application is synchronized for the first time there is no problem. Everything is correct. It is the second time that it causes a "FATAL ERROR SIGNAL 11". 
Always in the DELEGATE.synchronize("default") method.

On other devices always work properly, so I'm afraid that this is a bug due to the x86 processor tablet (SG Tab 10.1 3)

The error is:

```
05-22 11:57:56.749: D/houdini(18302): [18316] Unsupported feature (ID:0x10400184).
05-22 11:57:56.749: A/libc(18302): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdead0000 (code=1), thread 18316 (WebViewCoreThre)
05-22 11:57:56.799: I/DEBUG(7013): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-22 11:57:56.799: I/DEBUG(7013): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/santos10wifixx/santos10wifi:4.2.2/JDQ39/P5210XXUANB4:user/release-keys'
05-22 11:57:56.799: I/DEBUG(7013): Revision: '8'
05-22 11:57:56.799: I/DEBUG(7013): pid: 18302, tid: 18316, name: WebViewCoreThre  >>> com.example.prueba <<<
05-22 11:57:56.799: I/DEBUG(7013): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr dead0000
05-22 11:57:56.939: I/DEBUG(7013):     eax 00000000  ebx 610d0ac0  ecx 6228addc  edx 00000000
05-22 11:57:56.939: I/DEBUG(7013):     esi 22020020  edi 00000000
05-22 11:57:56.939: I/DEBUG(7013):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000043  xss 0000007b
05-22 11:57:56.939: I/DEBUG(7013):     eip 6208fbf3  ebp 610d0ad8  esp 610d0ab0  flags 00010246
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013): backtrace:
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):     #00  pc 00182bf3  /system/lib/libhoudini.so.3.3.3.43422
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):     #01  pc 000fdac0  [stack:18316]
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):     #02  pc 000f5092  /system/lib/libhoudini.so.3.3.3.43422
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):     #03  pc 000c6f8c  /system/lib/libhoudini.so.3.3.3.43422
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):     #04  pc 000f5887  /system/lib/libhoudini.so.3.3.3.43422
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):     #05  pc 001ae1f6  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):     #06  pc 000b9921  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):     #07  pc 001aed2d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):     #08  pc 00000000  <unknown>
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013): stack:
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):          610d0a70  00000000  
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):          610d0a74  00000000  
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):          610d0a78  00000000  
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):          610d0a7c  00000000  
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):          610d0a80  00000000  
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):          610d0a84  00000000  
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):          610d0a88  00000000  
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):          610d0a8c  00000000  
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):          610d0a90  00000000  
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):          610d0a94  00000000  
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):          610d0a98  00000000  
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):          610d0a9c  00000000  
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):          610d0aa0  00000000  
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):          610d0aa4  00000000  
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):          610d0aa8  00000000  
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):          610d0aac  00000000  
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):     #00  610d0ab0  610d0ac0  [stack:18316]
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):          ........  ........
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013): memory map around fault addr dead0000:
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):     bf844000-bf865000 [stack]
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):     (no map for address)
05-22 11:57:56.949: I/DEBUG(7013):     (no map above)
05-22 11:57:57.029: I/DEBUG(7013): !@dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_native -m 18302
05-22 11:57:57.029: I/BootReceiver(2299): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_01 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
```

Has anyone ever encountered anything like that? 
Have to do with the libraries "armeabi"?

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Sybase was a company, what Sybase product(s) are you referring to.  Also, you mention Sybase SMP - did you mean Sybase SUP?  SMP is the SAP Mobile platform that is the newer version (around 3.0 and newer) of the old Sybase Unwired Platform (SUP).  There are tags for those products so it is a good idea to replace a less useful tag with [sup] or [sap-smp]

Comment: I'm referring to SMP 2.3 patch 4, thanks for comment. I've changed the tag

Comment: more information required. There are 3 possible ways to create application for SMP 2.3. native application by using Generated Object apis, HWC application and Odata application. Please provide more information to figure out the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. We use Generated Object APi for build a native Android App that uses a WebView in one single Activity. When we call synchronize() from the html code through the Javascript Interface, the synchro throws the fatal error.